# COPY INTO snowflake table not working for internal stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on loading data into a Snowflake table using an internal stage using the `PUT` and `COPY INTO` command.

```
import snowflake.connector

conn=snowflake.connector.connect(
                user='username',
                password='password',
                account='account',
                )     

curs=conn.cursor()
conn.cursor().execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_snowflake")
conn.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE test_snowflake")
conn.cursor().execute(
    "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "
    "shoppers_table(first_name string, last_name string)")
conn.cursor().execute("CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE shoppers_table COPY_OPTIONS = (ON_ERROR='continue')")
conn.cursor().execute("PUT file:///Users/navid/Desktop/snowflake_test.csv @shoppers_table")
conn.cursor().execute("COPY INTO shoppers_table")
```

My CSV file looks like:

[image]

On running the code above, it creates a stage and the database, however the data does not get copied.

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY INTO` should reference internal stage `@shoppers_table`:

```
conn.cursor().execute("COPY INTO shoppers_table")
=>
conn.cursor().execute("COPY INTO shoppers_table FROM @shoppers_table")
```

---

Alternatively if the goal is to use table stage(`%` sign) - `@%shoppers_table`:

```
COPY INTO @%shoppers_table FROM (SELECT 'c', 'd');  -- put file in table stage

LIST @%shoppers_table;

COPY INTO shoppers_table;

SELECT * FROM  shoppers_table;
```